# sort unanswered questions by date

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I am sure this used to be possible. However now, when I select "unanswered" the query is obviously answered by sorting via votes received and I don't know how to sort unanswered questions by date, most recent questions first.

Comment: Have you tried the "Unanswered" link on the left sidebar?

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the "Unanswered" link on the sidebar on the left of the page, then the page you get has options for sorting the unanswered questions.  A direct link is: https://mathoverflow.net/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest